# Having some problems with printing files

Tags: printing, libreoffice, pdf, 22.04

While printing an a file using libre office or envice pdf reader with HP deskjet 2235 printer staright line of vertical borders are having small cuts[image: issue] how to solve this, not facing problem with windows using same printer.But the line is straight in horizontal border.

Comment: what flavour of ubuntu do you have and is the text broken in the same way as the line is,i am not sure this is os related.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy jelly, libre office version 7.3.3